# Is it possible to Customize highcharts drillup button

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is it possible to Customize highcharts drill-up button -- Please see the picture.

I have my own button which I am using to reload the chart. Can I apply my button style to highcharts drill up button to looks both same style... If yes how can I achieve this?

I want my Back button should look like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.drillUpButton.theme ?

Comment: @ewolden Thank you, I tried to overrride "highcharts-button"  "highcharts-drillup-button"  and "highcharts-button-normal" . set them !important as well.   But It just not working .. :(

Comment: Why do you want to use CSS classes if you can apply every style option through the `theme` object? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/drillupbutton/.

Comment: Hi @d_paul ,  The reason I want CSS is I want all of my button looks same in my full websites. Theme object has limited options, If i didn't missed anything. Like I want button should have background Images.. Just updating my Question with how my back button should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no option for `drillUpButton` to set symbol. Although, you can omit this inconvenience, by setting a SVG pattern (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) and apply it to `drillUpButton` by using fill attribute like this:

```
fill: 'url(#arrow)'
```

This way you can use images as button's background.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.drillUpButton
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wmvcah31/

Comment: Is it possible to use border-Radius

Comment: Sure, use the `r` attribute inside `theme` object. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L9ax1d43/.